# Bootstrap grid without sm , md and lg

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Found some div tag below way

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
```

what does `col-6` denote?  Know in bootstrap we can provide col-xs-* or col-sm-*, col-md-*, col-lg-*  in the bootstrap  but if i use col-6 will it apply to smart phone or tablets or laptops or desktops size?

Comment: Looks like a mistake. That's not valid grid class notation in Bootstrap 2 or 3 AFAIK.

Comment: Where did you find it. I think its was just a typo, or someone modified the css so that without -xs it would apply to the smallest breakpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked it doesnt exist in bootstrap, so you might have entered a typo in your css or maybe in the html, inspect it to see its css properties.

Also what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Using Bootstrap v3.0.1.    Thanks a  lot for the info