# Are Bootstrap's breakpoints for stacking divs vertically on different viewport sizes?

Tags: media-queries, bootstrap-4

Why does Bootstrap (I'm using 4) have column specific classes, if the columns are responsive regardless?

```
.col
.col-sm, md, lg, xl
```

Are these only for stacking divs on different screen sizes?  I can resize and see it, and I know that horizontally that .col only does horizontal, but are the breakpoints solely for stacking divs?

This did not help,
[Bootstrap grid without sm , md and lg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733903/bootstrap-grid-without-sm-md-and-lg)

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. sm, md, lg, etc.. are responsive tiers for different layouts (not necessarily "stacking"). Do you mean the [auto-layout cols](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)?

Comment: No.  I meant if you put the breakpoint, when I resize the window divs stack vertically.  If I only put col and no breakpoint like sm or md, then they stay horizontal, but just get very small.  I didn't know if that was the only purpose of the breakpoints for divs and the only way to make them stack vertically.  Should I just use flex-column instead?  I don't know how I missed that reference you put.  Thanks.